# Can not login to OpenStack Dashboard

Tags: juju, openstack

When i try to log in to OpenStack Dashboard i get this error."An error occurred authenticating. please try again later." I also saw that i need to point the dashboard toward keystone via the OPENSTACK_HOST, and also the CACHE_BACKEND must point to the keystone server's url. Can you please tell me how to do this?

Comment: How did you install openstack? Is it single-node or multi-node?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one useful blog on setting up of open stack via juju.

http://marcoceppi.com/2014/06/deploying-openstack-with-just-two-machines/

In short there are multiple services for open stack and they need to be interconnected, you need to create services identical to one's listed in the blog and have them interlinked in juju to get openstack running.